# DapperExtensions and Dapper.Contrib with non-dbo Schema

Tags: dapper-extensions

I'm using DapperExtensions v4.0.30319 and I'm trying to let Dapper.Contrib know that my schema is not DBO. I have provided:

```
public class EngineMapper : ClassMapper<Engine>
{
    public EngineMapper() : base()
    {
        Schema("vehicles");
    }
}
```

I understand from the DapperExtensions documentation (https://github.com/tmsmith/Dapper-Extensions/wiki/Customized-mapping-for-a-class) that this class will be automatically found using reflection?

But I also tried explicitly using:

```
DapperExtensions.DapperExtensions.DefaultMapper = typeof(EngineMapper);
```

Either way when I use Dapper.Contrib's:

```
SqlConnection.Insert(new Engine());
```

the resulting insert statement does not specify any schema.

How do I do an insert (or update, etc) using Dapper.Contrib where it uses the table schema which I specify?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `Table` attribute to show `schema` and `table` name together with a dot in between:

```
using Dapper.Contrib.Extensions;

[Table ("vehicles.YourTables")]
public class YourClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I'll have to try this. But I really hate to pollute my (database-agnostic) models with information that really belongs at the database layer.

Comment: Dapper.Contrib and Dapper Extensions are two separate libraries, so the Classmapper approach only applies to code using DapperExtensions. @vaheeds attributes approach is the right way to work with the Contrib library.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to also be able to map class to the custom schema. My project is asp.net core 2.2 Tried to decorate the poco with the `[Table("schema.Table")]` attribute, but `dapper contrib` won't seem to pick it up. Here are the proj. dependencies

[image]

However this approach did the trick:

[image]

See if that helps.